# Why my 100vw element has a strange left gap?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a box with three elements, and I also need a full-width of viewport element which place inside `item 2`

[image]

This is pen which show this problem https://codepen.io/in-in/pen/Nwxoar

I’m talking about the purple element (after), and I expect it to occupy the full-width of viewport but it has a strange left margin (41px)

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: tan;
}

.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.box__item1 {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.box__item2 {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: 500px;
  background-color: coral;
}
.box__item2::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
  content: "after";
  background-color: blueviolet;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.box__item3 {
      flex-basis: 100px;
      background-color: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box__item1"><span>item 1</span></div>
    <div class="box__item2"><span>item 2</span></div>
    <div class="box__item3"><span>item 3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because position absolute positions are relative to the nearest positioned element, in your case that's the `item 2` element, and that element's "leftmost" side is _not_ at the left border.  This is a pretty screwy way to get that element to show up there - what are you trying to accomplish other than a series of colored boxes?  (And in your margin calculation, 50% width refers to the `item2` container, not to itself)

Comment: The problem is the use of flexbox *in combination* with the weird positioning of the purple div.

Comment: Because the result of `margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw)` is not perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.box__item2` element has a relative position. I moved the position property to the `.container` element and added a top: 80px and set the height: 80px for`after`.

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: tan;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.box__item1 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 200px;
      flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.box__item2 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 500px;
      flex-basis: 500px;
  background-color: coral;
}
.box__item2::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
  content: "after";
  background-color: blueviolet;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.box__item3 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100px;
      flex-basis: 100px;
  background-color: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box__item1"><span>item 1</span></div>
    <div class="box__item2"><span>item 2</span></div>
    <div class="box__item3"><span>item 3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

link: https://codepen.io/greensleeves/pen/gXrOQx